# Laravel wire-elements package - How to use this with bootstrap theme?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

There is this package https://github.com/wire-elements/modal.

i have followed the steps to configure to implement the modal however i use a different CSS framework. My question is where is says :

**TailwindCSS
The base modal is made with TailwindCSS. If you use a different CSS framework I recommend that you publish the modal template and change the markup to include the required classes for your CSS framework.**

How do i get to do that because my modals are not showing though i have done exactly what is on the documentation i have done the following commands

php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire-ui-modal-views

php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire-ui-modal-config

set the config/livewire-ui-modal (include CSS) to true

Comment: Have you solve the problem? I'm having the same problem, from my understanding we need to modify this file resources\views\vendor\livewire-ui-modal\modal.blade.php from tailwind theme to bootstrap theme but I don't know how to change the markup, anyone can share some sample code?

Comment: Can you please share `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: @Haridarshan const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Comment: You should give it a try by having both bootstrap and tailwind css together [Tailwind & Bootstrap 5 together](https://dev.to/tanzimibthesam/how-to-install-both-tailwind-and-bootstrap-5-in-a-laravel-project-393h)

Comment: and may be with this you won't need to change the markup of modals as tailwind css will be available

Comment: I've tried this and it's working for me without any changes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to upgrade to their PRO edition to use Bootstrap features, unfortunately.
Here is what I learnt from their [wire elements Docs](https://wire-elements.dev/docs/getting-started/modal-component#start).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).